# Is "3-QBF" defined similarly to 3-SAT is PSPACE-complete?

Tags: computational-complexity, quantifiers, np-complete, satisfiability

Define 3-QBF to be the language of all true-valued quantified 3-CNF boolean formulas.

When talking about **NP**-completeness, SAT is reducible in polynomial time to 3-SAT, which means that 3-SAT is also NP-complete.

Does this work also when talking about **PSPACE**-completeness? Is 3-QBF also **PSPACE**-complete?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 3-QBF is **PSPACE**-complete.  The same scheme that reduces a CNF clause with more than three literals to a 3-CNF clause works to produce equisatisfiable 3-QBF clauses and thus formulas.  The bridge variables introduced to break up large clauses are existentially quantified and are placed in the innermost quantification group where they can be used to produce a satisfying assignment if one is possible in the original formula.

Comment: I think that the premise is wrong that QBF with CNF clauses is PSPACE-complete. I think that formulas for the TAUT problem cannot be efficiently converted to CNF.

Comment: See [Tseytin transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation), which allows the efficient transformation of any Boolean formula to CNF.  The use of extension variables prevents the exponential blowup of terms while keeping the resulting formula equisatisfiable, though not completely equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, I think that works. Be careful with the weak word "equisatisfiable" though: TQBF can be regarded to be about satisfiability only when no universal quantifiers are used. The Wikipedia article doesn't mention any quantifiers, but indeed it does seem applicable in this more general case.